Minimum Survey Respondents for Hypotheses I want to answer
I am an eager statistics noob, so apologies on the basic questions.
I am looking to send out a survey to a population that is large (people with diabetes who take insulin in the US) (~ 8.4 million)
Based on this I am aiming for 96+ survey responses overall (with a margin of error of +- 10%), with a goal of getting closer to 300 responses.
I have some hypotheses I want to look at in the survey results and will be doing some statistical testing

One hypothesis is "Hypothesis: There is a significant difference in  rating of importance of (xyz user need, just giving a fake example - being able to quickly calculate amount of insulin for a meal) based on time the user has been using insulin"
This would be a demographic question I collect (How long have you been using insulin for?), with a range of responses in months.
Since importance is a rating on a likert scale (ordinal), the groups are different, and I want to understand difference, I was thinking of doing the Mann-Whitney test. I specifically would like to understand if longer time using insulin would impact rating of importance on this one user need.

My question: Would I need a minimum of 96 respondents who answer in each bucket (for example 1 year or longer and 1 year or shorter) to aim for a stat sig response or would I just need to be looking at 96 overall for all respondents who answer this q. Also, if you have feedback on my approach feel free to weigh in.

Hi Christine. It's not clear to me what method you plan to use for your analysis, perhaps you should make that more explicit. Generally speaking, if you plan to use some statistical test, you should define your hypothesis more precisely. If the  difference you want to detect is very small, it may require a much larger sample size. So you should think about the kind of difference you want to detect. Alternatively, you could compute a confidence interval for the difference between groups. In this case, you'd have to specify how precise you want the CI to be in order to compute the sample size.

Thanks - Good point, just updated the post. I would be planning to do a Mann-Whitney test to compare the mean ranks of importance

To compute power (your ability to deem an effect significant if it's truly there), you'll need some estimate of effect size. Your goal is to reliably find a significant result if there is indeed a non-zero effect. If that effect is very tiny, you'll need a lot of data to reliably call it significant. If the effect is very large, you won't need much data to reliably call it significant. How different do you expect the groups to be? Imagine that one group actually chooses some result 0.01% more frequently - you'll need a lot of data to find that real (but tiny) effect.

Thanks, your edits really improved the question. If I understand correctly, you'll have a continuous independent variable (time using insulin) and an ordinal outcome (some rating). It's generally not advised to categorize continuous variables as you suggest (e.g. creating two groups "1 year or longer" and "1 year or shorter"). I'd suggest to ask what kind of analysis is the more adequate here, because dichotomizing like that may negatively affect your study and might unnecessarily increase the required sample size.

That makes sense - Thanks for the walk through with regard to effect size, new to this so I think that makes a lot of sense.

What you’re trying to do, albeit incorrectly (which is understandable) is a regression discontinuity design or regression kink design to determine the change. As your design involves something that doesn’t in a discrete intervention, it’s unlikely that discontinuity applies and, if anything kink design would apply (discontinuity is a vertical jump in the plot, such as glucose before and after insulin in 15min intervals. Kink is a stark change in slope,  an inflection point. The rise in opioid OD deaths after the crackdown on pills would be an example). Will explain more below.

@Christine I'd suggest you to add the tags "[tag:ordinal-data]" and perhaps "[tag:ordered-logit]" to your question, so people who follow these topics will be much more likely to see your question. I suggest the tag "ordered logit", because it may be a model relevant to your situation.

What you’re trying to do, albeit incorrectly (which is understandable) is a regression discontinuity design or regression kink design to determine the change. First I’ll answer your question then go into those designs.
For regression, you would need to do a power analysis (https://www.statskingdom.com/sample_size_regression.html) you can google how to do it manually if you want).
For things like a t-tests to comparative analysis 96 is generally large enough for any strata or group (simple random samples effectively have one stratum). However, if you want to compare groups/conduct subgroup analyses you need to ensure that all groups have adequate sample size. E.g. a class I TA’d drew a 127 person sample and only 7 were female student veterans thus it wasn’t possible to compare things like disability rating award rates between male and female student veterans for a survey. This problem is addressed by strategies sampling where you stratify your sample by the levels/subgroups of the relevant variables, ensuring that all subgroups have an adequate sample. So if I was concerned about veteran status, student status, gender, race, and disability status that would mean I would have at least 10 sub groups (depending on how you set up the variables). As you can see, this can present an issue if I simply base my sample on overall sample size and margin of error calculations. N=50 is enough to do a regression, but if I split that evenly between groups, i wouldn’t be able to do t-testing or much anything else. In your case, if you wanted to do that comparison, you’d want to double whatever you decide is an adequate sample size. Problem with your approach is that it’s an improper implementation of a proper method and that method probably wouldn’t be useful for this scenario anyway because there is no specific treatment, so discretizing the age variable likely wouldn’t be useful. It would be useful if there was some intervention at 1 yr because it is assumed that the responses right above and below that 1-yr mark would be similar and continuous absent the intervention.
However, As your design doesn’t include an intervention, it’s unlikely that discontinuity applies and, if anything kink design would apply (discontinuity is a vertical jump in the plot, such as glucose before and after insulin in 15min intervals. Kink is a stark change in slope,  an inflection point. The rise in opioid OD deaths after the crackdown on pills would be an example). There’s another possible method called interrupted time series but that’s way beyond anything you’ll know how to do for a while anyway and I don’t understand it well enough to say if it could be used.
With that being said, I would simply plot the data to see what your graph looks like. If the data plot is linear, including a cutoff value wouldn’t be useful. And it is possible that there’s even a nonlinear relationship for some reason. In reality, unless that plot shows a jump or stark change in the slope (think a kink in a pipe), a normal regression would suffice given that there’s no reason to expect a stark change of any kind because it is continuous and there’s no intervention to cause it. So plot your data and do a simple regression first. If the results don’t make sense, make a post with a screenshot of the plot and also the output data.
